# Python self defined function with None argument

Tags: python, pandas, function

I want to define my own function as below:

```
def myown(df, ADD1, ADD2 = None, OtherArgument_1, OtherArgument_2):
    tmp = df
    tmp['NEWADD'] = (tmp['ADD1'] + ' ' + tmp['ADD2']).str.strip()
    return tmp
```

I know this is incorrect so I can add `if` statement in the function.

```
def myown(df, ADD1, ADD2 = None, OtherArgument_1, OtherArgument_2):
    tmp = df
    if ADD2 == None:
        tmp['NEWADD'] = tmp[ADD1].str.strip()
    else:
        tmp['NEWADD'] = (tmp[ADD1] + ' ' + tmp[ADD2]).str.strip()
```

However, If I don know how many `ADD` inputs at first, how can I modify this?
For example, there are 5 `ADD` need to be combined this time and next time it may be 3. It is difficult to re-write function each time like this:

```
def myown(df, ADD1, ADD2, ADD3, ADD4, ADD5, OtherArgument_1, OtherArgument_2):
    tmp = df
    tmp['NEWADD'] = (tmp[ADD1] + ' ' + tmp[ADD2] + ' ' + tmp[ADD3] + ' ' + tmp[ADD4] + ' ' + tmp[ADD5]).str.strip()
```

Comment: you can check `*args` , `**kwargs`

Comment: I'm confused and I think I need to see an example to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using loops and lists like this:

```
def myown(df, add_args, OtherArgument_1, OtherArgument_2):
    tmp = df
    new_add = ''
    for i in add_args:
        new_add = new_add + tmp[i].str.strip() + ''
        tmp['NEWADD'] = new_add
```

Your add_args parameter must be a list, which looks like this:

```
add_args = [ADD1, ADD2, ADDn]
```